# Validating a textbox based on AJAX response before Save in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, configuration

In Admin Config, I have a textbox where i will enter a value.
When hitting on `Save Config` button.
The value from the Textbox is sent over through an AJAX call.
If the response is positive, it should save successfully. 
Else, it should throw an error and should not save.

**EDIT:** I tried with the code:

*system.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../Magento/Config/etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="Vendor" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>Vendor</label>
        </tab>

        <section id="Vendor_Module" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Vendor Module</label>
            <tab>Vendor</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_Module::Vendor_Module</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Settings</label>
                <field id="enable" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable Vendor Integration</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="public_api_key" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Public Vendor API Key</label>
                    <backend_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Config\ApiKeyValue</backend_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>

    </system>
</config>
```

*ApiKeyValue.php*

```
<?php 
 namespace <Vendor>\<Module>\Model\Config; 

class ApiKeyValue extends \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value {

   protected function _beforeSave() { 
     $value = $this->getPublicApiKey(); 
    //Throw exception $msg = __('Please check the error.'); 
    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException($msg); 
   } 
}
```

The Blank page when go to *STORES > Configuration*

Comment: see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should validate the data based on `_beforeSave` config action. We need to declare the custom backend model which extends from `Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value`

```
 <field id="custom_field" translate="label comment" type="textarea" sortOrder="70" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
     <label>Edit custom instruction of robots.txt File</label>
     <backend_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Config\CustomField</backend_model>
 </field>
```

Declare our custom config class:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config;

class CustomField extends \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value
{

    protected function _beforeSave() {
       $value = $this->getValue(); // Get the value
       ......
       //Throw exception
       if(empty($value)) {
          $msg = __('Your message here');
          throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException($msg);
       }
       ......
    }
}
```

See more: `vendor/magento/module-cookie/Model/Config/Backend/Lifetime.php`

Comment: How do i print the error on the Admin Config and stop from saving?

Comment: I tried it, but i am getting only a blank screen when i try to open
 Stores->Configuration page after clearing the cache.

ApiKeyValue.php
---------------------------
<?php
namespace <Vendor>\<Module>\Model\Config;

class ApiKeyValue extends \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value
{
    protected function _beforeSave() {
       $value = $this->getPublicApiKey(); // 
       //Throw exception
       $msg = __('Please check the error.');
       throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException($msg);
    }
}

Where am i wrong?

Comment: Did you take a look: `vendor/magento/module-cookie/Model/Config/Backend/Lifetime.php`? You can see a good sample. And where is `$this->getPublicApiKey(); `?

Comment: And where is `$this->getPublicApiKey(); `? I think this part causes the error. You should try with `$this->getValue();` for getting the current value of config.

Comment: I tried with $this->getValue(); first,It caused an error., and then i tried with $this->getpPublicAPiKey(); On calling this, i get the value of the textbox. But even this didnt help.

Comment: Also, I tried this prior
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/b1e56ed3b6f13f1ab780d8eddc33fc04cb6ecf75/app/code/Magento/Config/Model/Config/Backend/Email/Address.php

Even this gave me a blank screen on opening Stores->Configuration page

Comment: Hey! Please, post your `system.xml`. Seem that your issue is coming from the system xml config.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/2j0NkB here it is

Comment: Did you declare the acl for resource `<resource>Vendor_Module::Vendor_Module</resource>`?  Try to remove `<backend_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Config\ApiKeyValue</backend_model>` also? What happend?

Comment: When i remove ` <backend_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Config\ApiKeyValue</backe‌​nd_model>` - It works normally.

where to declare acl for resources? I dont have a acl.xml file under etc

Comment: But under System->user Roles. There is just one administrator with access to all the resources.

Comment: For the `beforeSave`, you should take a look `vendor/magento/module-cookie/Model/Config/Backend/Lifetime.php`. You should check if the value is empty, it will throw an exception. See my updated answer.

Comment: I tried. Now i am able to open the Configuration page. But my Module looks empty on the right side.

Comment: Did you clear Cache and try again? Check the `var` log? Is there any error log?

Comment: I tried. Now i am able to open the Configuration page. But my Module looks empty on the right side.

Comment: I think you need to declare the acl for `<resource>Vendor_Module::Vendor_Module</resource>`. Try to replace `<resource>Vendor_Module::Vendor_Module</resource>` with `<resource>Magento_Sales::config_sales</resource>`

Comment: Wow it worked perfectly now. I tried to recompile it. Thanks a ton @khoa 
You're my saviour :)